# Javascript onchange event .selectedIndex on the first element does not work

Tags: javascript, select, onchange

I'm trying to trigger a change event that shows the reference of a selected item below. So I've made the variable to keep track of .selectedIndex change it into a number and compare to an array that has all the references. Code works exept when I select back again the option Choissisez (= "choose"). I've noticed if I don't put return in the if, it checks the array twice (checked it with alert) and puts the second value as undefined ... any idea why?

Here's the code:

```
 <li id="mobileList" class="list-group-item">
 <select name="numbers" id="modele">
 <option value="42"/>One
 <option value="12"/>Two
 <option value="6"/>Three
 <option value="3">Four
</li>
 </select>
 <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </li>
<li class="list-group-item">
        <label class="col-md-4 duplicate-select">Référence :</label>
<span class="col-md-5" id="ref">                    </span>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item">
                <label class="col-md-4">IMEI :</label>
                <input type="text"/>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </li>   
 <script>                   
var listeRef = [555, "AUT", 753,751,758,851,858,857,"AUT"]; 
var refResult = document.getElementById("ref");
var mobile = document.getElementById("modele");
var refLength = mobile.length;

mobile.addEventListener('change', function() {
var produitSelectioner = mobile.selectedIndex;
        for(var i=0; i < refLength; i++){

        if(i = produitSelectioner)
        {    

            var choix = listeRef[i];              
            refResult.innerHTML=choix;
           produitSelectioner= "cancel"; 
           return;                
        }
  }
}, false);
</script>
```

Comment: `if(i = produitSelectioner)` assigns the value of `produitSelectioner` to `i`. To check for equality, you need to use the `==` or `===` operator

Comment: Oh yes silly me! Thank you for the quick answer ^^ don't need the return too!

Comment: Actually, you don't need any of it, you're getting an element by ID, and there can be only 1, as ID's are unique.